# WPF animation (scaling/translating multiple images at the same time)

Tags: c#, wpf, animation

I am working on a project in C# using WPF to attempt to make a program much like http://www.scaleofuniverse.com/.

I know it can easily be done in flash but I want to integrate the controls into other platforms (ie the new Leap motion and Kinect). I know I could rig it so that the kinect emulates key presses onto a flash game but i would really like to figure out making this in C#. I completed a few basic tutorials on basic animation and storyboarding but i've found nothing that indicates the project i want to complete can even be done! Am i biting off more than i can chew or am i over-complicating the program somewhere? I am only in the design stage so i do not have any source code for review (still completing tutorials). I really want to know if this project is even plausible before I continue working on it.

Comment: There is 1 thing that is not possible with WPF: raising the dead.  That could be done in 3D I guess

Comment: Fair enough, you know of any tutorials that go into more advanced animation? I searched for hours and completed any of the basic tutorials i could find but each tutorial only deals with 1 animation type usually and for this i would need to  scale the image and move the image at the same time. I have been trying to mess with the animations in C# on my own but 95% of the time the changes i make break something. I just dont have the time to spend messing around with C# i need some guidance! =)

Comment: It can be done, but not by simply animating a ScaleTransform. *Scale of the Universe* covers more than 50 orders of magnitude. If you would try to do this with a single scaled drawing you would inevitably run into heavy rounding errors, as WPF calculates with double-precision coordinate values, which offer a precision of roughly 15 decimal digits.

Comment: My thought process was to use multiple images and scale/translate them individually as they continue to move until they are off screen at which point they get removed and a new image appears and gradually grows larger. There wont be just one image on the screen at one time either I just cant figure out how to syntactically do this.

Answer (score 0):

It definitely can be done in WPF. Here is an example of a custom zoom control for WPF http://www.ab4d.com/ZoomPanel.aspx.

Comment: Thats very useful for zooming in/out on a single image however my program needs to scale multiple images at a time and translate them to different spots at the same time. Sorry my use of Zoom in/Zoom out in the title is misleading! ill see if i can correct that

Comment: If you had a zoom control of some sort wouldn't you just need to set a threshold on some desired zoom percentage and then swap the image? For it to be a seamless transition, I imagine you would need to preload your images and stage them behind the current image.